disappears all windows from screen when monitor disconnnects suddenly from my laptop
I have an issue . when suddenly there is a power cut , and my monitor disconnects , from laptop which is attatched by HDMI , then i cant see apps screen( 2 x super key press ) as well as the window screen ( 1 x super key press )
using ubuntu 24.04 LTS
